# Why did Amanda Waller's helicopter shoot off some fireworks after take-off?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad

In Suicide Squad (2016), Amanda Waller's helicopter shot some fireworks after take-off.

[image]

What is the purpose of it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Those aren't fireworks.....they're **flares** used to decoy heat-seaking missiles.

There had already been one helicopter downed by a missile. They were just taking precautions.

[image]

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flare_(countermeasure))

> A flare or decoy flare is an aerial infrared countermeasure used by a plane or helicopter to counter an infrared homing ("heat-seeking") surface-to-air missile or air-to-air missile. Flares are commonly composed of a pyrotechnic composition based on magnesium or another hot-burning metal, with burning temperature equal to or hotter than engine exhaust. The aim is to make the infrared-guided missile seek out the heat signature from the flare rather than the aircraft's engines.

[image]

Comment: (warning: spoilers in comment, and I don't know how to hide them)  Note that their use in Suicide Squad was hilariously and completely wrong.  You don't just spam flares unless you have a reason to, because you can run out of flares.  This was clear as day when they proceeded to run out of flares and then got shot at by a heat seeking missile.

Comment: I don't disagree but, in fact, they weren't hit by a missile...they were *pulled* from the sky by a tentacle/tendril of some kind.